# Android: Why my progress dialog not disappear?

Tags: android, android-fragments, progressdialog

I have the following code. I'm using 4 fragment on an activity. The fragment has a webView. But as you know, preparing all the data for fragment takes long time. So I wanted to use a progress dialog while the data preparing. Yeah, I called it and now, just trying to dismiss the progressDialog after the progress is done. But I think it like me a lot. Not going anywhere. Any help?? Thanks.

(Note: I have erased the code from my project. Now added back in here so it's possible that I've made some little mistakes. Don't stuck in that.)

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity()) ;       
    if (wv != null) {
         wv.destroy();
    }     
     wv = new WebView(getActivity());
     wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);                     


     wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", true);
             Log.e("Progress:", ""+progress);
             if(progress == 100){pd.dismiss();}
            }

        });


     wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

         @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
                Log.e("Connection:", "NO");
            }
      @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {   
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
     });    

     wv.loadUrl("http://mobile.twitter.com/Yali_Spor");  


     wva = true;

     return wv;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this-

```
   final ProgressDialog pd;      
if (wv != null) {
     wv.destroy();
}     
 wv = new WebView(getActivity());
 wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);                     


 wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", true);
         Log.e("Progress:", ""+progress);
         if(progress == 100){pd.dismiss();}
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

On each progress change you make a new ProgressDialog so you have a lot of dialogs at the end eventually and you only dismiss the top one this way when progress is 100

Comment: I thought this too. But I tried to call the ProgressDialog from inside the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method. With this, there should be just 1 pd but it is not gone.